# UI приложения, XAML или C#?

Tags: c#, ui, windows-phone-8, xaml, windows-8

Добрый день. Решил написать небольшое приложение для Windows 8 (Windows Store). И, так как раньше я писал на Windows Forms, появился вопрос по ModernUI.

Интерфейс приложения будет представлять из себя сетку (Grid), но количество строк, столбцов и их содержимое будет меняться в зависимости от действий пользователя. Возможны даже случаи, когда внутри строки, будет появляться еще один Grid со своими строками. То есть, интерфейс должен быть очень гибким.

Я сразу полез в MSDN, [открыл пример UI приложения](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752271%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) и увидел, что даже там дается пример как на C#, так и XAML. Стало быть, у меня есть три варианта:

1. Писать интерфейс на C#, там же
       динамически его и менять.
2. Писать основу интерфейса на XAML, а
       затем динамически его менять из кода
       C#.
3. Писать все на XAML. Насколько я
       понимаю, там тоже можно динамически
       подставлять нужные классы, то есть,
       я прописываю все основные варианты
       на XAML, а потом из C# подставляю
       нужные, в зависимости от состояния.
       Так как с XAML знаком недавно - не
       уверен, что так можно.

Вопрос - как правильно? Или все не так, нужно лучше учить мат.часть?)

Отдельная благодарность тому, кто подскажет хорошие и проверенные книжки для желающего писать приложения под WP8, WinRT, Win8. Нашел несколько, но мб кто подскажет оптимальную.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Таки мат.часть, в сторону MVVM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Писать интерфейс на C# -- крайне неправильно: у вас из прогрессивного продвинутого WPF получится ретроградский WinForms. Вам нужно сделать вашу логику представления на XAML с небольшими добавлениями на C#, а модель отображаемых данных -- на чистом C#.

Я бы посоветовал отойти от `Grid` и подумать о семантике: *что именно* вы хотите показать?

Скорее всего, это *список* каких-то сущностей, например, людей. Если так, ваш выбор -- не `Grid`, а `ListView` или даже `ListBox`. Для того, чтобы выбрать, как именно будет отображаться строка, используйте `ItemTemplate` (или возможно `ItemTemplateSelector`, если хотите, чтобы шаблоны были различными). В шаблоне вы сможете отобразить любые поля в любом количестве, на ваш выбор.

Одним словом: идите не от внешнего вида, идите от смысла того, что вы хотите показать пользователю.

Да, и почитайте про MVVM, без него никуда.

Comment: Благодарю, уже читаю MVVM на MSDN. Касательно интерфейса, то это будет нечто похожее на OneNote на WinRT: http://habrastorage.org/storage2/24d/db4/888/24ddb48888590fd4999929b4a4273be7.png . Там тоже несколько колонок, количество отображаемых на экране меняется. Возможно, у меня верстка будет немного посложнее, но, в целом, идея такая.

Насколько я понимаю, про XAML можно почитать в литературе по WPF. Осталось найти хорошую книжку )

Comment: @DeniDoman: Неплохая книжка по основам WPF -- "WPF 4 Unleashed", автор Adam Nathan. Ссылка из [гугла](https://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+4+unleashed) приведёт вас на rutracker.

Comment: С такой вёрсткой вам надо наверное `DockPanel` для контейнера колонок, `ListView` или `TreeView` для самих колонок. Читайте, разбирайтесь.

Answer (score 1):

Отличная книжка по C# под Win 8:
Пугачев, Ширев, Кичинский "Разработка приложений для Windows 8 на языке C#" достаточно подробно все описано для самостоятельного изучения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно  сам Popup и всё его содержимое описать на XAML— легко и быстро. То как сделать это на С# говорится в той книге, что я советовал выше, страница для изучения 83 «отображение всплывающих окон и меню».